# SharePoint List UserCustomAction, In whole sitecollection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I'm getting this to work if I choose a specific list to add the action to. Is there an easy way to enable this custom action on all document libraries in the whole sitecollection?

Code sample:

```
function createUserCustomActionList() {
    var cmd = "<CommandUIExtension><CommandUIDefinitions><CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children\">" +
        "<Button Id=\"DiaryAction.Button\" TemplateAlias=\"o1\" Command=\"DiaryCommand\" CommandType=\"General\" LabelText=\"Dela flera\" Image32by32=\"https://eolusvind.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/_layouts/15/1033/Images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23\"" +
    " Image32by32Top=\"-271\" Image32by32Left=\"-109\"  />" +
        "</CommandUIDefinition></CommandUIDefinitions><CommandUIHandlers>" +
            "<CommandUIHandler Command =\"DiaryCommand\" CommandAction=\"javascript:alert('Hej');\" EnabledScript=\"javascript:SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length > 1;\" />" +
    "</CommandUIHandlers></CommandUIExtension>";

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Dokument');
    var uca = list.get_userCustomActions();

    var oUserCustomAction = uca.add();
    oUserCustomAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView');
    oUserCustomAction.set_commandUIExtension(cmd);
    oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(100);
    oUserCustomAction.set_title('Dela flera');
    oUserCustomAction.update();

    ctx.load(list, 'Title' ,'UserCustomActions');

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        alert('Custom action created for ' + list.get_title())
    }, function (sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach for *registering custom button in Documents libraries across site collection*:

- use `RegistrationType` set to 2(ContentType) and `RegistrationId` set to `0x0101` (for `Document` content type) to register custom action via content type
- use *site* scope user custom action to apply changes across all site
  collection

**Example**

```
var cmd = "<CommandUIExtension>" +
"<CommandUIDefinitions>" +
"<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children\">" +
"<Button Id=\"ClickAction.Button\" TemplateAlias=\"o1\" Command=\"ViewCustomPropertiesCommand\" CommandType=\"General\" LabelText=\"View Custom Properties\" Image32by32=\"/_layouts/15/1033/Images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23\" Image32by32Top=\"-1\" Image32by32Left=\"-171\"  />" +
"</CommandUIDefinition></CommandUIDefinitions><CommandUIHandlers>" +
"<CommandUIHandler Command =\"ViewCustomPropertiesCommand\" CommandAction=\"javascript:console.log('View Custom Properties');\" EnabledScript=\"javascript:SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length > 0;\" />" +
"</CommandUIHandlers>" +
"</CommandUIExtension>";

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var customAction = ctx.get_site().get_userCustomActions().add();  //1. apply via site scope user custom action
customAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView');
customAction.set_commandUIExtension(cmd);
customAction.set_sequence(112);
customAction.set_registrationType(2);  //2.set to ContentType
customAction.set_registrationId("0x0101");  //2.set Document content type
//customAction.set_title('Document custom button');
customAction.update();

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    console.log('Button has been registered');
}, function (sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```

Comment: Nice Vadim! I tried to load customactions from the "Site" object, but I did not use registrationtype or registrationID. Big thanks!